# How can I redefine multiplication?

Tags: customization, arithmetic

For instance, I want `0 Infinity = 0`

I tried this: `Unprotect[Times];Times[Infinity,0]=0;Times[0,Infinity]=0;Protect[Times];`

But this did not work.

Comment: To reiterate the warning already given: modifying basic arithmetic functions will very likely break so many things in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do not do this. You'll break everything. Better to define your own operator and use that.

But if you must, this works by  defining upValue of `Times`

```
Unprotect[Times];
Unprotect[DirectedInfinity];
Unprotect[Integer];
Times[Infinity, 0] ^:= 0
Protect[Integer];
Protect[DirectedInfinity];
Protect[Times];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What does `^:=` do?

Comment: @Anixx  `^:=` defines UpValue of function.  See [TransformationRulesAndDefinitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html)